# Snowpark - Create multiple sessions in Snowpark (Snowflake)

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm currently learning how to use snowpark and I wanted to know if this was possible to create multiple sessions.

I have a preconfigured session with the handler like this :

[image]

And I tried to create another session using the Session.builder of the snowpark package like this :

```
class connection():
    def __init__(self, user, password, account, role, warehouse, database, schema):
        self.connection_parameters = {
            "user" : user,
            "password" : password,
            "account": account,
            "role": role,
            "warehouse": warehouse,
            "database": database,
            "schema": schema
        }
        self.session = Session.builder.configs(self.connection_parameters).create()

    def get_table(self, tablename):
        df = self.session(tablename)
        return df
```

And after running the worksheet (with the filled connection_parameters) I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Worksheet, line 28, in main
  Worksheet, line 19, in __init__
  File "snowflake/snowpark/session.py", line 232, in create
    return self._create_internal(conn=None)
  File "snowflake/snowpark/session.py", line 238, in _create_internal
    ServerConnection({}, conn) if conn else ServerConnection(self._options)
  File "snowflake/snowpark/_internal/server_connection.py", line 138, in __init__
    self._conn = conn if conn else connect(**self._lower_case_parameters)
  File "snowflake/connector/__init__.py", line 50, in Connect
    return StoredProcConnection(**kwargs)
  File "snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 178, in __init__
    raise ProgrammingError(
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Connection was already created. We don't allow user to create their own connection inside a stored procedure. Please use the connection in the provided session from the handler.
```

So I wanted to know if this was possible to create multiple sessions in Snowpark, or maybe is it because the Snowflake App environment and not a local one (jupyter, conda, ...), if not how can I create multiple sessions/connections ?

Comment: you can create multiple session object if you work with Snowpark in Jupyter or elsewhere. When you work with the Python Worksheets in UI it is not possible. Technically the worksheet is already a session, and you cannot open a new session inside the active one, basically this is what the error message means. You can open a new worksheet to create another session, or use Jupyter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the worksheet is already a session, and it is not possible to create a new session inside the active one, basically this is what the error message means.

(In Snowflake every worksheet as a new session with its own connection parameters such as current_role, current_database etc.)

To create and work in different sessions in Snowflake UI, you can just create new worksheets.

Alternatively, you can use an external connection using Jupyter or simillar. Then you will be able to create different sessions objects, even with their own [connection parameters](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/creating-session#creating-a-session).

Comment: thanks, yes I tried ended up trying the jupyter solution and it worked fine. I was trying to avoid setup up new environments, ... given that a large part was on snowflake. But worked fine in the end, thanks for the answer